# ASP.NET Check UserName Availability using ClientSideEvents

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

This is the first post for me in this the greatest website.

Is there any possibility to change isValid property from OnCheckUserName function?If so how can I do that?

Actually in this example there is a code block which use web service:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function OnloginIDValidation(s, e) {
            if (e.value.toString().length > 0) {
                e.errorText = "UserName is not available";
                PageMethods.CheckUserName(e.value.toString(), OnCheckUserName);
            }
        }
        function OnCheckUserName(unavailable) {
            if (unavailable == true) {
                e.isValid = true;
            }
            else if (unavailable != true) {
                e.isValid = false;
            }
        }
    </script>

    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
     <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txt_loginID" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txt_loginID">
          <InvalidStyle BackColor="#FFF5F5">
               <Border BorderColor="Red" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
          </InvalidStyle>
          <ClientSideEvents Validation="OnloginIDValidation" />
     </dx:ASPxTextBox>
    </asp:Content>
```

```cs
    [WebMethod]
    public static bool CheckUserName(string userName)
    {
        if (Membership.GetUser(userName) != null)
        {
          return true;
        }
        else
        {
          return false;
        }
    }

    private void ApplyValidationSummarySettings()
    {
        vsValidationSummary1.RenderMode = (ValidationSummaryRenderMode)Enum.Parse(typeof(ValidationSummaryRenderMode), "BulletedList");
        vsValidationSummary1.ShowErrorAsLink = true;
    }

    private void ApplyEditorsSettings()
    {
        ASPxEdit[] editors = new ASPxEdit[] {txt_loginID};
        foreach (ASPxEdit editor in editors)
        {
            editor.ValidationSettings.ValidateOnLeave = true;
            editor.ValidationSettings.SetFocusOnError = true;
        }
    }
```

It doesn't work 
I hope to help me how can i fix it. 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [ASPxTextBox.ClientInstanceName](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxEditBase_ClientInstanceNametopic) attribute to some value, e.g. textBox1. Then use [ASPxClientTextBox.SetIsValid](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientEdit_SetIsValidtopic) method in `OnCheckUserName` method. 
Like this:

```
    function OnCheckUserName(unavailable) {
        textBox1.SetIsValid(unavailable == true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check below links using JQuery & AJAX for username availability

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Check-UserName-Availability-in-ASP.Net-using-JQuery.aspx

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Check-Username-Availability-in-ASP.Net-using-AJAX-PageMethods.aspx

Comment: @MoustafaFawzi please up vote correct answer and one which is helpful.